# Windows 10 as a router to accept connections over wifi and send to vpn gateway

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, routing

I am trying to send all traffic from a device in my local network to a remote network via VPN. Since the device itself cannot be a VPN client (vpn client is not available) the idea is to send all the traffic from the device to a router which can establish a VPN connection to remote network. As a router I have configured Windows 10 box, enabled RRAS (Routing and Remote Access Service) and configured the device to use this win10 box as a default gateway. It works, but the moment win box has VPN connection established, device cannot reach remote network. What am I missing?

More details: Device (D1) has IP address: 192.168.1.12 (255.255.255.0) and default gateway set to 192.168.1.10

Windows 10 box (win10box): 192.168.1.10 with default gateway 192.168.1.1 which is connected to the ISP (Internet).

With this configuration device D1 can successfully reach Internet using win10box as it's default gateway and traceroute shows correct path (win10box is included as a first hop).

When win10box establishes connection to the remote network via VPN (using IPSec), it receives correct settings (IP: 178.168.1.100, gateway: 178.168.1.1) and able to access remote network resources and go out (to Internet). But the moment VPN connection is established in win10box the device D1 is unable to access either Internet or remote network resources. Tracert shows first hop followed by timeouts. The routing table on win10box after VPN is established looks normal - has two default gateways (my local network and vpn remote network def gateway with lower metric) and win10box can successfully ping remote network and access Internet via it.

What am I missing? How can RRAS be configured to support routing into VPN tunnel on win10 (not server)?

Why, when windows 10 (with RRAS - Routing and Remote Access Service enabled) works as a router successfully but stops when VPN connection is established?

I tried doing Internet Connection Sharing for my VPN adaptor (right-click on vpn adapter, sharing tab and choose my lan connection in the drop down) - got *Error 87: the parameter is incorrect*

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered Site to Site VPN from your router?  I do this to client sites.

Comment: I did :) I can't marry the fritz!box with mikrotik on the other side so far. But the configuration I am trying to achieve has other benefits (the actual setup is a bit more complicated) so I'd like to have it running.

Plus I am confused what am I not getting about windows rras :)